# BuddyPress: subscribers can't change password

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I'm dealing with a sudden (as much as tedious) bug which is affecting my BuddyPress website: subscribers can't change their password anymore!!! In a few words, administrators can change their password as usual, but subscribers always get the following error message: "Your current password in invalid.".

Did anyone have the same problem? How can I fix it? Is it by chance a BuddyPress bug?

Thanks

Comment: I forgot the installation details: WP version is 3.3.1 and BP version is 1.5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the bug: the last version of BuddyPress requires the user current password as well but my theme files were not up-to-date.